# iOS safari cannot open uber web site, says address is invalid

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, mobile-safari, uber-api

I have searched for the related address invalid issues in stacker flow, but didn't get any solution for uber specific web site not being open. Here is a video of what's happening http://tinypic.com/r/zyisra/9

Thanks in advance for any pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter your client id (in numbers and characters, the one you have from Uber) in the URL, instead of "YOUR_CLIENT_ID" at the end of the url

Comment: @Tushar Did you got any solution?